# combine consecutive awk calls into one

Tags: linux, unix, awk

I'm trying to use `awk` to get a specific number out of a text file. The number can be identified by **consecutively** applying three rules:

1. Get only lines starting with the string `Name(s):`
2. In the 6th of the said lines, get the 3th element. Elements are separated by one or more spaces
3. take 100 minus the number found

I got it working with two piped `awk` calls:

```
cat file | awk '/^Name\(s\):/' | awk -F " " 'NR==6 {printf "%2.2f", 100 - $3; exit}'
```

How can I combine the two `awk` calls into one?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Untested as the `file`was not there but:

```
$ awk '/^Name\(s\):/ && ++c==6 {printf "%2.2f", 100 - $3; exit}' file
```

Comment: Whoops, did I just uselessly use a `cat`... fixed.

Comment: Yes, does what it should. `cat` is obviously obsolete now. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score -1):

You can put the AWK statements into a file -example myprogram.awk- and use it like

```
awk -f myprogram.awk
```

Comment: this isn't an answer and wouldn't help the OP get closer to an answer.

Comment: The "not an answer" flag [doesn't apply to content](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/185073/168269). That's what voting is for. Technically, this is an answer.

Comment: I didn't flag it as such, I just commented an downvoted.

Comment: Multiple times, I moved from multiple single-line awk commnds to an external awk script, as I was adding functionality. I think my answer is therefore the best answer, for legibility, maintainability and scalability as complexity grows, it's better to externalize into its own file.

Comment: But it doesn't answer the question. Sure, by using a script file it *looks like* any number of statements is reduced to one call, but of course in reality they aren't.

Comment: It is the creation and destruction of awk process from the shell what causes the bad performance of the original code, when multiple awk commands are piped. A single call of awk program solves that.